# Edit files in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, permissions

I want to modify a file in vista ( C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts ) but I can't write it to disk.

Similar thing happen with other files that are not under my user directory. C:\Users\me

I am in the administrator group.

What is needed to edit these files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With UAC turned on, you're not running as an administrator normally.  That's why you can't edit it.  The simplest thing to do is to right-mouse click notepad and choose "run as administrator".  You'll be prompted with a UAC prompt.  You should then be able to edit and save the file.

Comment: Thanks Knox... I just had this scenario perplex me in Win7 when trying to change that file. I decided to let UAC do its job, and I am running as non-admin in Win7. It didn't occur to me. I would have expected a UAC prompt, but none came. Now I know; thanks.